# Four dimension String array for an android project

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

I am developing an android application. I am using 4 activities . 3 are listveiws and last one is displaying texts and image about an article.
Can i use a single four dimensional string for this application.

```
static final String values[][][][] =
{
{ // age
  {  // categories
    { "CAN I TYPE PARAGRAPH 1 INSIDE ??" },
   {"CAN I TYPE PARAGRAPH 2 INSIDE ??" },
{  // category2
    { "CAN I TYPE PARAGRAPH 1 INSIDE ??"" },
    { "CAN I TYPE PARAGRAPH 2 INSIDE ??"" }
  }

  },
```

};

can i use this variable in all my classes? am confused please help me .

HOW TO USE A STATIC VARIABLE IN ALL ACTIVITIES ??

Comment: Yes, you can use 4D-String array in Java (and also, Android). However, since there is no more detail about the requirement, I cannot comment whether it will work or not.

Comment: While you can do that, it does not sound like a good design. Also, from the example it seems you can do with 3 dimensions since there is only one element in the innermost array.

Comment: how can i access a single string array in all my activities? where should i initialize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously creating a 4D string array is possible, but not sure if it is useful in your case.
For your question about how to access a string everywhere :

In your project in the folder `res/values` add an xml file called for example `strings.xml`
If you started with an example provided by eclipse this file is usually already present there.

The file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApplicationName</string>
    <string name="your_custom_string">A custom string can be written</string>
</resources>
```

then in your code you access the string with `R.string.your_custom_string`.
For example if if you want  the application name as your activity title use :

```
setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

you can even create string arrays like that

```
<string-array name="custom_font_size_array">
    <item>12</item>
    <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
    <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
    <item>25</item>
</string-array>
```